# TextBlock.FontFamily not using font in print

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-7

I'm working on a simple POS WPF app for printing receipts without a Print Dialog. I need to use a narrow font, so I chose [NK57 Monospace Cd Bk](http://www.1001freefonts.com/d/16151/nk57_monospace.zip). On Windows 10 it works, but on Windows 7 I'm still printing only using the default font. I tried the target printer (Epson TM-T20II), regular printer and print to PDF, the problem occured every time. Also I tried a few different Windows 10 and Windows 7 computers, W10 worked every time, while W7 failed every time.

I tried so far:

- Install the font into the Windows 7 and use it directly: new FontFamily("NK57 Monospace Cd Bk"). The font was found in InstalledFontCollection (maybe I tested it by using *Font.Name == fontName*, but the point is the test passed), but not used in print.
- Load the font directly from .ttf file: new FontFamily(new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "#NK57 Monospace Cd Bk", UriKind.Absolute), "NK57 Monospace Cd Bk")
- Pack the font with the app: new FontFamily("pack://application:,,,./Fonts/#NK57 Monospace Cd Bk") or new FontFamily("pack://application:,,,./Fonts/#NK57 Monospace Cd Bk");
- Use PrivateFontCollection, which is widely recommended, but it's not supported in WPF.
- Use new Font("...") instead, but I didn't find a decent way to convert it to FontFamily.

Nothing worked on Windows 7, most of it worked in Windows 10. Simplified code sample below (using PDF print to save paper).

```
var pd = new PrintDialog();
pd.PrintQueue = new LocalPrintServer().GetPrintQueue("Microsoft Print to PDF");
pd.PrintTicket.CopyCount = 2; // number of copies
pd.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;

FixedDocument document = new FixedDocument();
document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize = new Size(pd.PrintableAreaWidth, pd.PrintableAreaHeight);

FixedPage page1 = new FixedPage();
page1.Width = document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Width;
page1.Height = document.DocumentPaginator.PageSize.Height;

//var fontReg = new FontFamily("NK57 Monospace Cd Bk");
//var fontReg = new FontFamily(new Uri(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "#NK57 Monospace Cd Bk", UriKind.Absolute), "NK57 Monospace Cd Bk");
//var fontReg = new FontFamily("file:///" + AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "#NK57 Monospace Cd Bk");
//var fontReg = new FontFamily("pack://application:,,,./Fonts/#NK57 Monospace Cd Bk");
var fontReg = new FontFamily(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Fonts/"), "./#NK57 Monospace Cd Bk");

TextBlock t = new TextBlock();
t.Text = "This is a test";
t.FontFamily = fontReg;
t.FontSize = 14;
page1.Children.Add(t);

PageContent page1Content = new PageContent();
((IAddChild)page1Content).AddChild(page1);
document.Pages.Add(page1Content);

pd.PrintDocument(document.DocumentPaginator, "Print");
```

Any ideas what's wrong? My only working solution so far is to upgrade customer's system to Windows 10 (which will be done sooner or later, just will delay shipping of the otherwise completed app).

Thank you so much in advance for your help.

Comment: Might not be supported, or you may have to check your printer driver settings, depending on what printer manufacturer, model, and driver you have. Some printers will print only fonts they already have in ROM; they can't download TrueType or other font formats. Usually you can set the printer driver settings to rasterize the text in those cases, but this can be disabled in some cases. And of course in some cases, you don't get the option. You need to dig around in the printer settings to see what you can do with this particular driver. Consider testing with XPS driver to rule out code issues.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Please, does the driver settings apply for PDF as well? It didn't work printing to PDF either. I'm starting to think it's really not supported in W7, although I'm not considering that an edge case scenario (is really nobody printing from WPF using custom fonts?). I'll try to fiddle with printer settings more anyways, thanks for the tip.

Comment: @mikiqex I have had my share of trouble with loosing the font when printing with custom fonts to a regular laserjet. I ended up with quite the hack; generate an image of the control and print that image instead. I would love to see an answer to this question of yours. Do you retain the font when using a regular printer?

Comment: I decided to install my old Win 7 into VMware and to be confused even more, print into PDF (using PDFill PDF&Image Writer) is working there! :-/ I used the most basic approach, installed the font and new FontFamily("NK57 Monospace Cd Bk");

Comment: _"does the driver settings apply for PDF as well?"_ -- it depends on the driver. IIRC, Win 7 didn't have a built-in "print to PDF", so you must be using a third-party driver. Each driver will have it's own particular behavior. And the behavior may even be configurable (including the ability to embed a font in the document).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After it worked in clean virtual Windows 7, I tracked myself back and because I tried a LOT of different font styles, I suspect I originally shipped the app with a wrong font. I made sure this time the correct font is installed in customer's Windows 7, reverted the code back to

```
var fontReg = new FontFamily("NK57 Monospace Cd Bk");
```

and it's working now. Anyway, I claim all other methods (using link to a ttf file, packing ttf file with the app) unsupported on Windows 7, because it worked on Windows 10 but didn't work on Windows 7, and there wasn't a room for the same wrong-font mistake.

Thanks, Peter and Heki, for your suggestions.